# Flatten Nested schema in DataFrame, getting AnalysisException: cannot resolve column name

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, nested

I have a DF:

```
 -- str1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- str2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- str3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- str4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- b1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b3: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b4: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- c1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- c3: integer (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to flatten it, to do that I have used code below:

```
  def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null):Array[Column]=
  {
    schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
      val colName = if (prefix == null) f.name else (prefix + "." + f.name)

      f.dataType match {
        case st: StructType => flattenSchema(st, colName)
        case at: ArrayType =>
          val st = at.elementType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
          flattenSchema(st, colName)
        case _ => Array(new Column(colName).as(colName))
      }
    })
  }


val d1 = df.select(flattenSchema(df.schema):_*)
```

Its giving me below Output:

```
 |-- str1.a1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- str1.a2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- str1.a3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- str2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- str3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- str4.b1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- str4.b2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- str4.b3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- str4.b4.c1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- str4.b4.c2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- str4.b4.c3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

Problem is arising when I am trying to query it:

`d1.select("str2").show` -- Its giving me no issue

but when I do query on any flattened nested column

```
d1.select("str1.a1")
```

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`str1.a1`' given input columns: ....
```

What I am doing wrong here? or any other way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: given inputs columns: .... is the more important information in this question :) please provide it

Comment: @Alexandros Biratsis: str1.a1 is present in the list of input columns in the error

Comment: I see only .... @Apurw!

Comment: Yeah i have not pasted the full error but the column names which I am trying to query are present in the list of given input columns in the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark does not support `string` type column name with **dot(.)**. Dot is use to access child column of any `struct` type column. If you will try to access same column from dataframe `df` then it should work since in `df` it `struct` type.